# Absolute value of complex numbers $|a+bi|$

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

I didn't understand why the absolute value of $(a+bi)$ is equal to $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ but not $\sqrt{(a+bi)^2}$ like $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$

if $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ is right and if we give $x = a+bi$ it should be $\sqrt{(a+bi)^2}$

and why this proof is wrong:

> $z=a+bi$
> $|z|^2=z^2$
> $|z|^2=(a+bi)^2$
> $|z|=\sqrt{(a+bi)^2}$

Note: I don't want "Cartesian representation of a complex number" I don't see it as proof.

So I wrongly generalized the equation of the absolute value of a real number:

> my generalization:
> $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ (only right for real numbers)
> right definition: (by my understanding so far)
> $|a_1x_1+a_2x_2...a_nx_n| = \sqrt{\Sigma_n{(a_kx_k)^2}}$

Comment: The $|?|$ here does not mean absolute value. It means the norm (or modulus) of the complex number $z$.

Comment: $\lvert a+bi\rvert=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is like $\lvert x+0i\rvert=\sqrt{x^2+0^2}$

Comment: So by your definition we would have $|i| = \sqrt{i^2}=\sqrt{-1}=\pm i$ or something like that?

Comment: no just $\sqrt{i^2}$ there is no more simplifications (according to my proof (not a real proof but I don't know why it is false))

Comment: Why are you not allowed to substitute $-1$ for $i^2$ in the expression $\sqrt{i^2}$? Ordinarily, in any mathematical expression, when $a=b$ you are allowed to substitute $b$ in place of $a$.

Comment: Actually, you are right its equal to $i$ but not $±i$. sorry for my mistake at "there is no more simplifications" words

Comment: Alright, so I just wanted to establish the fact that in your system $|a+bi|$ is allowed to take a complex number, but its value is not necessarily a real number. The important point is that under the usual definition $|a+bi|$ is a non-negative real number, and it satisfies various useful identities and inequalities, for example a version of the triangle inequality. I doubt that your definition satisfies all those useful identities and inequalities.

Comment: To be explicit, under the usual definition the triangle inequality holds, meaning that for any three complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ we have $$|z_1-z_3| \le |z_1-z_2| + |z_2-z_3|$$ Does your system satisfy anything like that?

Comment: I agree with @LeeMosher. If you want to conserve the equality $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ and the usual notion of the square root of a positive real number, you have a problem. Suppose that $\sqrt{i^2} = i$ ; then $i^2 = i \cdot i = \sqrt{i^2} \cdot \sqrt{i^2} = \sqrt{i^4} = \sqrt{1} = 1$, but $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: @NaNoS that so wrong becouse:
$x^2 = a$ then $x = ±\sqrt{a}$
but $y = -\sqrt{a}$ then $y^2 = a$ then $y = \sqrt{a}$ (you did that)

Comment: Your proof is wrong because $|z|^2\ne z^2$.  That's just plain false.  But what is true is $|z| =z\overline z$.  So $|a+bi|^2 = (a+bi)(a-bi)= a^2 - (bi)^2 = a^2 -b^2i^2=a^2 +b^2$...... Note if $x \in\mathbb R$ then $\overline x = x$ (because $x = x+0i = x-0i=\overline x$ and so FOR REALS we have $|x|^2 = x\overline x = x\cdot x = x^2$.

Comment: I did what ? I don't understand your message @EgemenYalın. By definition, $i^2 = -1$, right ? Where did I say that $y^2 = a$ implies $y = \sqrt{a}$ ... ?

Comment: We can define anything we want to be anything we want so we *could* define $|z|_{abs}$ as $|z|_{abs} = \sqrt{z^2}$  (once we actually define *which* of the two square roots we want to use) but... that's function doesn't really give us any *use*.  It doesn't do any of the things we *want* $|z|$ to do.  ... I suppose it has an interesting fact that if $x$ is real, then $|x|_{abs} = |x|$ but we can come up with an infinite number of functions were that is true.  Say $|z|_{weird}=|Re(z)| + 57\cdot Re(z)Im(z)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a complex number $z$, we don't speak about the "absolute value of $z$" but we speak about the **modulus** of $z$ denoted by $|z|$. If the algebraic form of $z$ is $a + ib$, then by definition you set $|z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. Note that this definition extends the absolute value on $\mathbb R$.

Also, if $z = i$, how do you define $\sqrt{i^2}$ ? More generally, how do you define the square root of a complexe number ? How can you distinguish the two roots ?

Comment: it $\sqrt{i^2}=i$ its equal to i, I mean its equals to $|i|$

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your answer. You know that $i^2$ has two roots in $\mathbb C$ : $i$ and $-i$. There is no canonical choice to define $\sqrt{i^2}$ between $i$ et $-i$. You know that in $\mathbb R$, every positive number $a$ has two roots : a positive one and a negative one and we set $\sqrt{a}$ as the positive one. This is because $\mathbb R$ has a notion of order that behaves well under addition, multiplication and so on that we can define a function "square root". It is impossible to define such order on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: "We usually prefer positive numbers" It's not a preferred thing we must use positive it is all meaning of the square root symbol.

Comment: That's why I deleted this sentence.

Comment: @EgemenYalın " It's not a preferred thing we must use positive it is all meaning of the square root symbol."  But what if we *cant*?  If $w = 3 - 4i$ and $v = -4+3i$ then $w^2 = (4-3i)^2 = 4^2 -2\cdot 4\cdot 3i + (3i)^2= 16-24i -9=7-24i$ and $v^2$ also equals $7-24i$.  So $\sqrt{7-24}$ is either $-4+3i$ or it is $4-3i$.  Neither of those are "positive".  So which is it?

Comment: fleablood: No, w^2  =  -7 - 24i  ≠  v^2. (For two complex numbers to have the same square, they must either be equal or be negatives of each other.)

Comment: The terms "absolute value" and "modulus" apply to both real numbers and complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the definition of the absolute square $|z|^{2}$ of a complex number $z = a + i\,b$ while keeping the definition of the complex conjugate in mind, i.e., $z^{\ast} = a - i\,b$, such that overall,

\begin{equation}
|z|^{2} = z z^{\ast} = \left(a + i\,b\right)\left(a + i\,b\right)^{\ast} = \left(a + i\,b\right)\left(a - i\,b\right) = a^{2} + b^{2}\,.
\end{equation}

Obviously, the absolute value is given by

\begin{equation}
|z| = \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Wait why is $|z|^2=zz^∗$

Comment: This is the correct answer, +1. OP has incorrectly generalized the behavior for real $z$. In the case that $z$ is real, then $zz^*=z^2$, but for nonreal $z$ it is not so.

Comment: @EgemenYalın "Why is $|z|^2=zz^∗$".  Because .... that is usually the definition given.  If $z = a+bi$ then $z^* = a-bi$ and $(a+bi)(a-bi) = a^2 + b^2$.   Of course a definition always comes down to someone sitting down and saying "This is the definition" and in complex number that's what we did.  $|z| = \sqrt {zz^*}$ by def.  Now, you *could* sit down and say "The definition should be $|z|=\sqrt{z^2}$" but you'd be too late.

Answer (score 1):

Why should $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$?  That's a *consequence* of the definition.  Not the definition itself.  If $x\in \mathbb R$ then $x = x + 0i$ and $Re(x) = x$ and $Im(0) = 0$.   And $|x| = \sqrt{Re(x)^2 + Im(x)^2} = \sqrt{x^2 + 0^2} = \sqrt{x^2}$.

The idea is that $|z|$ is a *norm* which can be thought of as "the distance" from the origin".  It can have a more formal and precise definition but that's the "organic" definition.  But some of the fundamental aspects of a norm/distance for $0$ are: its a real, non-negative value and that only the origin has a zero norm.

For real numbers, a positive number is its own value distance from $0$.  That is $7$ is $7$ units from $0$ and $\pi$ is $\pi$ units from $0$.  So if $x > 0$ then $|x| = 0$.  And negative values or their values but in the opposite direction.  $-19$ is $19$ units away from $0$ but in the negative direction. And $0$ is $0$ distance from $0$.

So we can *describe* the $|x|; x\in \mathbb R$ as $|x| =\begin{cases}|x|=x&if x>0\\ |x|=-x&if x< 0\\|x|=0&if x=0\end{cases}$.  But that's only a description and it only works if $x\in \mathbb R$.

And some people don't like step-wise definitions.  They might note that if $x \in R$ then $x^2 \ge 0$.  and for every $y>0$ there are two real numbers, one positive, $x_1$, and one negative, $x_2$, so that $x_1^2 =x_2^2 = y$ and they notice $x_2 = -x_1$.  They call the positive one $\sqrt y$.

With that we can note.  If $x > 0$ than $\sqrt{x^2} = x$.   If $x=0$ then $\sqrt{0^2} = 0$. and if $x < 0$ then $-x > 0$ and $x^2 = (-x)^2$ and $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$.  In these three cases we always have $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ (as described above) and so they can use $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$ as description for absolute value.

BUT THIS ONLY WORKS IF $x$ IS A REAL NUMBER!!!!!

Complex numbers we need a concept distance from origin.  $1 = 1 + 0i$ is clearly one unit away, as is $i = 0 + 1i; -1=-1 +0i;$ and $-i=0 +(-1)i$.  But what of $3 + 4i$?  Well.... if we think of this geometrically (I'm kind of kicking myself and and debating whether I should bring this up) then $3+4i$ is a $3$ units in the positive real direction and $4$ units in the up-ward $i$ direction and so a sensible norm would be to use the pythogorean theorem.  The square of the distance of the $3$ units plus the square of the distance of the $4$ units, is equal to the square of the hypotenuse distance from $3+4i$ to $0=0+0i$.  So $|3+4i|^2 = 3^2 + 4^2$ and $|3+4i| =\sqrt{3^2 + 4^2}=\sqrt{25} =5$.

In general:  $|z| = \sqrt{Re(z)^2 + Im(z)^2}$.

And what's nice about it is it works for reals as we already defined it.  If $z \in \mathbb R$ then $Re(z) = z$ and $Im(z) = 0$ and $|z| =\sqrt{Re^2(z) + Im^2(z)} =\sqrt{z^2 + 0^2} = \sqrt{z^2}$.  But only if $z$ is real.

.....

All this brings up the issue when you are expanding from one set of numbers to another, from whole numbers to include the negative integers; from the integers to include the rationals; from the rationals to include the irrationals; from the reals to include the imaginary and than to include all the complex-- we will always have to expand or definitions and concepts.  The important thing is to recognize and keep and modify what is basic and necessary from that which is coincidental and incidental.  That $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ is *incidental* as real numbers are always positive, negative, and $0$.  But that $|x|$ is a normed non-negative real distance is fundamental.  As we move from reals to complex where numbers are *not* always positive, negative, and $0$ having $\sqrt{z^2}=|z|$ will not required or possible but having $|z|$ be a normed non-negative real distance will.

Comment: This is really funny, I was actually reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028017/arithmetic-proof-of-absolute-value-function-of-complex-numbers?rq=1) where you gave a similar answer (not as complete as this one though).

Comment: Well, I can't remember what I did yesterday much less what I wrote six years ago.  That question was probably shorter as that OP asked "what" whereas this OP asked "why".

Answer (score 0):

Absolute value gives you distance of a real number from the origin regardless of sign. The concept of a modulus generalizes this to complex numbers. In the complex plane, numbers may not just be on the real line, but anywhere in the plane. The concept of distance from the origin is still maintained and is given by the Pythagorean Theorem, $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. This reduces to the absolute value for complex numbers on the real line.

While $z=a+ib$ is the Cartesian representation of a complex number, it can also be represented as $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $r$ is the modulus and $\theta$ is the argument, $\theta = \arctan (b/a)$ and in general $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$.

Essentially, the definition of the modulus is $|z|=\sqrt{z \bar z}=\sqrt{(a+ib)(a-ib)}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

$a+ib$ is not a distance, but may have multiple distances associated with it. One might have reason only to care about the real part, or just the imaginary part. Each of these gives you some concept of distance to associate with the complex number.

Comment: okay but why my proof is wrong

Comment: because $|z|^2 = |z^2|$ is not true in general. This only works for (purely) real numbers.

Comment: You use the wrong definition. $|z|^2\ne  z^2,$ but $|z|^2=z\bar z$. What you give only works for real numbers and doesn't produce an absolute value, a distance. Only real numbers are distances. You are partially right $\sqrt{(a+ib)^2}=a+ib$.. But there is another complex number whose square gives you $(a^2-b^2)+2iab$ so $\sqrt{(a+ib)^2}$ isn't necessarily $(a+ib)$. The other complex number has the same real  part but argument $\theta= \arctan(ab/\sqrt{a^2-b^2})+\pi$